# How to compute $VaR_\lambda(X_n)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, quantile

I have the following problem.
Let $X\in L^\infty$ and $\lambda\in(0,1)$, we define
$$VaR_\lambda(X)=\inf\{m\in\mathbb{R} : \mathbb{P}(X+m<0)\leq\lambda\}.$$
I have to prove that $VaR_\lambda(X_n)=0$, where $X_n:=1_{[ \lambda+\frac{1}{n},1]}.$
I calculated $\mathbb{P}(X_n+m<0)$ in this way:
$$\mathbb{P}(X_n+m<0)=\int_\mathbb{R} 1_{[\lambda+\frac{1}{n},1]} 1_{(-\infty,-m)} \frac{1}{1-\lambda-\frac{1}{n}} \, dx=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{-m-\lambda-\frac{1}{n}}{1-\lambda-\frac{1}{n}} &\ \text{ se}\quad -1<m\leq -\lambda-\frac{1}{n}\\
1&\ \text{ se}\quad m\leq -1 \\
0&\ \text{ se} \quad m> -\lambda-\frac{1}{n}.
\end{array}\right.$$
Now, $\frac{-m-\lambda-\frac{1}{n}}{1-\lambda-\frac{1}{n}}\leq \lambda$ if and only if $m\geq \lambda^2+\lambda(\frac{1}{n}-2)-\frac{1}{n}$, the minimum of this parabola is attained in $\lambda=1-\frac{1}{2n}$, then we found $m\geq-1-\frac{1}{4n^2}$ but we have the condition $-1<m\leq -\lambda-\frac{1}{n}$ too, so it must be $-1<m\leq -\lambda-\frac{1}{n}$.
At the same time, if $m> -\lambda-\frac{1}{n}$, $\mathbb{P}(X_n+m<0)=0\leq\lambda$, so I will say that
$$VaR_\lambda(X_n)=\inf\{m>-1\}=-1.$$
I don't know what is wrong... maybe I have to found the maximum of the parabola?

Comment: What does the indicator $1_{[\lambda+1/n,1]}$ represent here?

Comment: Honestly I don't know... but I forgot to say that the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is given by the unit interval [0, 1] and the
Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I assume $n>0$ and that you mean $X_n:=1_{u\in [\lambda+1/n,1]}=1_{u \geq \lambda+1/n}$ for $u\sim \text{Unif}(0,1).$ If so, then note that

$$P(X_{n}<-m)=\begin{cases}
0, & m\geq0\\
1, & m<-1\\
\lambda+1/n & m\in[-1,0)
\end{cases}.$$

It's clear $P(X_{n}<-m)\leq \lambda$ for $m\geq 0$, so the infimum of the set of such $m$ is zero, as desired.

Comment: I don't understand why $X_n:=1_{u\in [\lambda+1/n,1]}=1_{u \leq \lambda+1/n}$

Comment: @MathLover sry that was a typo-corrected it